# How to Map my input data

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datagridview, c#-3.0

My input string is `VALVE,GATE,SH_NAME:VLV,GATE,VLV_NOM_SIZE:4-1/16IN`

I want output like this (I want output in datagridview)

```
COLUMN_1              COLUMN_2
 VALVE
 GATE
 SH_NAME                VLV
 GATE            
 VLV_NOM_SIZE           4-1/16IN
```

Comment: So what have you tried ? And what's the error youve got ?

Comment: @Astro I do't know how to write code for this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
string str = "VALVE,GATE,SH_NAME:VLV,GATE,VLV_NOM_SIZE:4-1/16IN";
string[] Rows = str.Split(',');
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2");
foreach (string AddRow in Rows)
{
   string[] Row = AddRow.Split(':');
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row);
}
```

Comment: One more request. How to put empty column2 cell into "NULL"

Comment: I do not understand what you want, but the code can be expanded by adding the condition before add to Grid                 if (Row.Length < 2)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref Row, 2);

                    Row[0] = "Empty Column1";
                    Row[1] = "Empty Column2";
                }